# How can I implement a class structure that allows to an instance of a subclass to change to an instance of another subclass of the same class

Tags: swift, class, object

I'm trying an item object that can be a note (just a string of text as property) or a task, so having a status, priority,a due date, etc. etc. as additional properties.

It would be possible transforming at runtime a note item in a task item and vice-versa.

I'm thinking how to implement this, I started defining a class structure having "item" as principal class and two subclasses (note and task) but I can't understand how managing the transition between the two subclasses

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Swift, at least not in any way that you'd use as a general tool. (It is possible in ObjC via isa-swizzling, and that can be bridged into Swift, but even in ObjC you'd never want to use it for this kind of problem. It's a very tricky tool, not a general purpose solution to types.)

Instead of complex class substitution, you want to redesign this. There are several approaches. You can just convert types (see the `init(copying:)` methods):

```
protocol Item {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var name: String { get set }
    var contents: String { get set }
}

struct Note: Item {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var contents: String
    init(copying item: Item) {
        self.id = item.id
        self.name = item.name
        self.contents = item.contents
    }
}

struct Task: Item {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var contents: String
    var complete: Bool = false
    var dueDate: DateComponents?

    init(copying item: Item) {
        self.id = item.id
        self.name = item.name
        self.contents = item.contents
    }
}
```

Or, you can separate out additional properties and swap them (this approach is ideal if Item is a class, but I'd highly recommend trying to make Item a struct).

```
protocol ItemProperties{}

struct Item {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var contents: String
    var properties: ItemProperties
}

// No additional properties for notes
struct Note: ItemProperties {}

struct Task: ItemProperties {
    var complete: Bool = false
    var dueDate: DateComponents?
}

var item = Item(id: UUID(), name: "", contents: "", properties: Note())

// convert to task
item.properties = Task(complete: false, dueDate: nil)

// Convert back to note
item.properties = Note()
```

That said, if you only have Tasks and Notes, I'd avoid overthinking this until you have a clear sense of what you'd add in the future. I'd consider just a simple struct with a type enum:

```
enum ItemType {
    case note
    case task(complete: Bool, due: DateComponents)
}

struct Item {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var contents: String
    var type: ItemType
}
```

You can access these values using `switch` or `if case let`:

```
switch testItem2.type {
case let .task(complete: complete, due: due):
    // Handle complete and due
    break
case .note:
    break
}

if case let .task(complete: complete, due: due) = testItem2.type {
    // Handle complete or due
}
```

Sometimes it's convenient to create optional methods:

```
extension Item {
    var complete: Bool? {
        if case let .task(complete: complete, due: _) = type {
            return complete
        }
        return nil
    }
}

if let complete = testItem2.complete, complete {
    // If this is a task and complete
}
```

The syntax around enums is sometimes a little clunky. If you have more than a couple of properties for the associated value, I highly recommend wrapping them up in a struct:

```
enum ItemType {
    case note
    case task(TaskProperties)
}

struct TaskProperties {
   var complete: Bool
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the GREAT reply. I'm using the struct solution. If I create a struct with task type (var TestItem2 = Item(name: "name", contents: "content", type: .task(complete: false, due: "tomorrow"))) I don't understand how retrieve the value from it. (eg. TestItem2.type....) Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Barring a few tricks used in Objective C, a Swift instance can’t change it’s type at runtime. For one, different instances have different sizes, so there’s no good way to really make that work.

What you’re reaching for is something similar to [SmallTalk’s `become:`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/290908/109689) message, which you can send to an object in order to get all references to it, program-wide, to be replaced with a reference to some other object instead. It’s cool, but leads to some confusing designs, and has some pretty brutal performance implications. You don’t really want this.

The exact best solution would depend on your specific use case. You haven’t provided much detail. The obvious/simple option is for each subclass to have an initializer that lets you create e.g. a new note from a task.

However, this won’t automatically update all references to the old note to point to the new task. If that’s something you need, you would need to add a layer of indirection yourself, where all item references point to items (which Item no longer has any subclasses), which themselves contain ItemDetails (or something like that) which are subclassed by NoteDetails and TaskDetails. Within the Item, the details can be switched back and forth between being a note or being a task, while all outstanding references to the wrapping item remain valid.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your reply. Concerning the use case, imagine a list of notes and tasks. What I' trying to implement is a feauture allowing to transform a note in a task and vice-versa, so adding a check box, etc. etc. Maybe, being having the note just a subset of the properties of a task, it would be easier doing one class only putting a property that identify the item type (note or task) and putting the properties that refer to the task as optional. What do you think?

Comment: That’s a pretty common anti pattern, you’d essentially be replacing polymorphism with conditionals, which is the opposite direction you’d want to go https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: @ManuelZompetta you haven’t answered whether or not you need that behaviour that “all references to one should switch to point to the other after conversion”

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is by using a mixed design, of both structs and enums:

```swift
enum Item {
    case note(Note)
    case task(Task)
}

struct Note {
    var text: String
}

struct Task {
    var title: String
    var status: Status
    var priority: Priority
    var dueDate: Date?
    // ... other props
}
```

Switching between `Note` and `Task` would then be a simple matter of replacing `self` within the enum:

```swift
extension Task {
   init(note: Note) {
        self.init(title: note.text, status: .pending, priority: .low, dueDate: nil, ...)
    }
}

extension Item {
    mutating func convertToTask() {
        guard case let .note(note) = self else { 
            // already a task, do nothing
            // alternatively, you can throw an error
            return 
        }
        self = .task(Task(note: note))
    }
}

// look, I have a `Note`
var item: Item = .note(Note(text: "something to do"))

// but now I have a `Task` :)
item.convertToTask()
```